# React Native create a rounded skewed button

Tags: android, button, react-native

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmmMT.jpg

I would like to make this kind of button in react-native android

Tried multiple ways but nothing worked. 
Any idea how i could make this?

Comment: please share your previous efforts with us.

Comment: Well i tried to make it with skewed transform but is not working on android Y.Y

And right now im tring to use react-native-svg still reading about this.

Comment: use a TouchableOpacity with an image  in it?